# TextSearch for multiple locations

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

I have a list of store names that I want to do a textsearch on and find their locations. All I have is the name of the stores. I want to do a single search for all the names at the same time, is the possible? I tried creating multiple requests, but it didn't work well with something else I am doing. Here is what I am trying now.

```
var queryString = "";
for (var i = 0; i <= Stores.length - 1; i++) {
    if (i != Stores.length - 1) {
        queryString += Stores[i].Name + " AND ";
    } else {
        queryString += Stores[i].Name + "";
    }
}

var request = {
   location: location,
   radius: RADIUS,
   query: queryString
};

service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
//Do a text search for the stores in the database in the area defined by RADIUS
service.textSearch(request, callback);
```

But the status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK check keeps returning false. So does anyone have any idea how to create a single query string that queries for multiple locations?

Answer (score 0):

The [Places API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#TextSearchRequests) returns twenty matches at a time (up to a total of 60).  It does not support multiple requests in the same transaction.

Answer (score 0):

Try just one query and check if it works. If it doesn't work, check the value of PlacesServiceStatus object.